# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable?

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error when I run the code below:

> 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

I have searched stackoverflow, but cant find a answer to my question... Please help me!

```
def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    arrayOLines = fr.readlines()
    numberOfLines = len(arrayOLines)
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines, 3))
    classLabelVector = []
    index = 0
    for line in arrayOLines:
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index, :] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
        index += 1
    return returnMat, classLabelVector
```

and this is result...

```
>>> datingDataMat,datingLabels = kNN.file2matrix("datingTestSet.txt")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dennis Yang\PycharmProjects\mlaction\kNN.py", line 28, in file2matrix
    for line in arrayOLines:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I bet what you've posted here is different from what's in your script. You probably have something like `arrayOLines = fr.readlines` in your file. That means that you assigned the method to `arrayOLines`, but not the data. Otherwise, that exception should not be thrown.

Comment: readlines() is not an iterable! Try iteating on the numberOfLines variable